# growth limit on muscle

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, human-evolution

Is there any biological limit on muscle growth in human body, one can keep pushing body and keep growing more and more muscle but somewhere it must become diffcult for body to sustain those cells right?

Comment: Funfact: Actually there is no increase in number of muscle cells, they only get hypertrophied when the muscles become big.

Comment: @JM97 but sure larger cell need large energy reserve to stay alive , so it can go to infinity?

Comment: But there may be a limit above which they can't show hypertrophy?

Comment: @AlwaysConfused thats exactly my question, just for fun ,"CAN I TURN INTO HULK if keep wprking out :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Natural athletes have to deal with [MSTN gene](https://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/gene/MSTN).

> The MSTN gene provides instructions for making a protein called myostatin.
>
> This protein normally restrains muscle growth, ensuring that muscles do not grow too large.

Just look at the top natural athletes. There are a lot of them who train for 20+ years and still can't be as large as those athletes who take steroids. Here are some examples of professional natural athletes(Bobby Pandour, Georg Hackenschmidt)
[image: Bobby Pandour]
[image]

With steroids you can exceed all natural limits up until your body meets its boundaries, often accompanied by serious health issues.